# Can a character know Druidic without having any levels of druid?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, languages

Related to my answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/27590/4563).

Druidic is a special language in that no race can take it as a bonus language (even those who can choose any language specifically say [except Druidic](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#humans)) and cannot be learned with [Speak Language](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/speakLanguage.htm). Druids are [forbidden from teaching it to a non-druid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#druidBonusLanguages), on penalty of [losing all spellcasting and supernatural abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#exDruids).

So *can* a character know Druidic without having any levels of druid?

Comment: Side question for the DM: Since Druidic is so secret, dare I say, "sacred" what happens when one of the druidic orders discovers that you've learned their language?..especially if you learned it via some nefarious way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Plot: Learn it from someone who knows it

One would presume that should a druid decide to teach you Druidic, then you *could* spend a skill rank or two on Speak Languages to learn the language. That would be a DM’s call and probably quite rare, but it could happen. A blighter (*Complete Divine*) certainly wouldn’t care about teaching the language, for example.

Mind reading, memory access, or simple eavesdropping on a druid teaching a new druid may also suffice to be allowed to use Speak Language to learn Druidic. Note that the druid may lose his class features even if you force or trick him into teaching you though.

And of course, if one can find a nondruid who knows the language, that person would have no reason to refuse to teach you.

#### Magic: Speak all the languages

There are magical means to understand languages; [*comprehend languages*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/comprehendLanguages.htm) and [*tongues*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/tongues.htm) would give one the ability to temporarily understand and speak Druidic.

A [*crystal mask of languages*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/items/universalItems.htm#crystalMaskofLanguages) would also be capable of doing the trick. Oddly enough, while the *crystal mask of languages* requires that the crafter speak five languages, and then grants knowledge of five languages, nothing says they have to be the same five. Thus a psion who knows several languages could craft one that grants knowledge of Druidic.

Note that none of these actually teach you the language; they all last only as long as the spell does, or as long as you wear the item.

#### Epic: Polyglot feat

The [Epic] feat [Polyglot](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/feats.htm#polyglot) says you know all languages, so that includes Druidic. Language barriers are probably not your greatest concern at level 21, though. I suppose some Dragon abuse could get you the feat earlier, which in this case wouldn’t even be game-breaking.

#### Prestige: Loremaster *or* Race: Tibbit

This is the most useful one: the [loremaster](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/loremaster.htm) prestige class gives bonus languages at 4th and 8th level. This class feature simply states that the loremaster can choose “any new language”—it doesn’t exclude Druidic like racial bonus languages do, nor does it invoke the Speak Languages skill.

Likewise, the tibbit race from *Dragon Compendium* includes “Bonus Languages: Any. Tibbits travel far and wide and their curiosity pushes them to learn a number of languages,” in contrast to the human entry of “Bonus Languages: Any (other than secret languages, such as Druidic). See the Speak Language skill.” Again, no prohibition on secret languages, no reference to the Speak Language skill.

Either of these could be oversights and errors, but neither has been corrected (and both books have seen errata), so I for one am willing to take them at their word.

And while Druidic itself does say that it is “a secret language known only to druids,” 3.5 has a very important rule known as “specific-trumps-general.” In this case, I would argue, the general rule is that only druids known Druidic. After all, they get it free and everyone else has to work quite hard to get it. But clearly it *is* possible to learn the language in general (see previous points), so the statement that *only* druids know it is not absolute. Polyglot specifically supersedes it. So, I would argue, does the loremaster’s or tibbit’s bonus languages. However, this is only a case I am making: you could argue the reverse, that the Druidic rules are the more specific. You will have to discuss it with your DM.

Comment: "Secret language known only to druids." I read that to supersede other things where it's not listed. In other words, unless it's specifically included then just exclude it.
That is just my interpretation though, yours also seems valid.

Comment: I read it at LitheOhm did, as to me "any language" sounds general, and "only to druids" sounds specific... -- however, as druids loose their features for teaching it, that obviously means they *can* teach it, even if at a high cost. Unless you consider the language a class feature and they could somehow lose it as soon as they try teaching it?

I'd be interested if a de-facto druid (e.g. high level ranger role-played a particular way) could be taught without making the druid lose his features...

Comment: @Julix LitheOhm’s position is inconsistent with numerous other rules which explicitly call out Druidic as special, to which Loremaster is a notable exception. Other classes that allow the learning of a language either exclude Druidic, or reference Speak Language, which does. In any event, the rules do not provide an opportunity for druids to teach *any* non-druid the language (without losing class features), no matter how “druid-like” the character may be. A DM could easily waive that as befits the setting and character, of course, the rules just don’t specifically mention the possibility.

Comment: It's a good point, that other language adding bonuses clarify exclusions and these ones don't.

Comment: @Julix Where do you get that druids lose class features for teaching it? As far as I can tell, the books simply say you can't learn it, and leave what's stopping you up to a setting detail. Certainly, a druid losing their class features by teaching it, while harsh, seems far too little, actually, to justify the degree of secrecy that demonstrably is maintained on it. Find a druid who already lost their powers for some other failing (there are plenty of those around in most worlds), and bribe them to teach it to you. Spend a bunch of time spying on druids and decipher it. Learn from a Blighter.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon [Ex-Druids](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#exDruids): “A druid who [...] teaches the Druidic language to a nondruid loses all spells and druid abilities”

Comment: @KRyan Ah, there it is. Still seems like much more must also be in play to justify it actually remaining a secret for long.

Comment: Indexing Fun: Druidic can seemingly by gained by shaping a *soulspeaker's circlet* (*MoI* 87), but the DM must determine to what degree this counts as "knowing" the language. Between the *Epic Level Handbook* and *Complete Adventurer* was published *another* yet *general* feat named Polyglot (*Dragon* #323 90) that, in context, appears only to share its name with the epic feat; it allows a creature to "learn a language… as a bonus language" without restriction, yet humans and half-elves remain barred from picking secret languages as bonus languages (*PH* 13 and 18, respectively).

Comment: Although it's possibly an oversight, the race tibbit (*Dragon Compendium Volume 1* 21-5) has this entry: " Bonus Languages: Any. Tibbits travel far and wide and their curiosity pushes them to learn a number of languages" (25), which unlike the *any* of, for example, humans, does *not* exclude secret languages like Druidic and Gith. Maybe the tibbit learns it from eavesdropping on druids in cat form? Anyway, with a generous DM, a tibbit is (*ahem*) a little closer to alternative entry into Fochlucan lyrist.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah, was about to, hah.

Answer (score 4):

A further alternative method to learn Druidic could be a extremely challenging **Decipher Script** using collected notes written in Druidic and knowing the context. However even just finding written Druidic equivalent of the [Rosetta Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_Stone) (Most likely written in Druidic, Elven and Sylvan) would be a quest in itself as I imagine it is rare one of a kind marker of extreme importance.

It should be noted that this method isn't **RAW** and was a previous house ruling however if allowed by the DM gives your character an excellent roleplay opportunity to learn a language and provide plot hooks for adventures.

I would also like to mention there is nothing at all stopping a Druid from teaching (or being forced to teach) Druidic to someone in the case of an emergency and then *atoning* later.

Comment: Are you aware of any rules that allow Decipher Script to learn a language? You could use Decipher Script to figure out a particular passage in Druidic (particularly given a Rosetta Stone), but I’m not sure it’s enough to actually learn the language. It’s a good idea but I’m curious if there is any rules back-up. The second point is good and valid.

Comment: I have just been talking to the DM of my previous online campaign during which we had a similar situation learning Infernal. It seems it was a house rule he had put in place I'll update my answer above accordingly.